# Best practice of Read-Modify-Write Rest Api Design

Tags: api, rest, api-design, idempotent

I have a restful api to update the bunch of objects on the server side. For example, I have an object like this:

```
{
  counter: int,
  bit_mask: int,
  other_value: string,
}
```

on the client side, I want to do some update based on the inner method on the server side, like:

```
{
  counter++,
  bit_mask.some_inner_method(some_value),
  other_value = new_value
}
```

I want to expose an idempotent and atomic rest API for this kind of update instead of read it to the client-side and writing it back to the server side. Here is my naive thought on the body of this API

```
{
  overwrite: {
    other_value: "new_value",
  },
  updates: [
    {
      property: "counter",
      operator: "inc"
    },
    {
      property: "bit_mask",
      operator: "some_inner_method",
      params: ["some_value"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I think this should be a common use case, but I didn't find any discussion about it online. Is there any better solution to this scenario?

Comment: Json based there is jsondiff. Keep in mind rest means statefull. To process a uri is more like processfull and not covered by rest.

Comment: I don't think there is a standardized media-type/schema that does what you want.  It _might_ be useful to review RFC 6902, and design a similar "it's a list of operations with arguments" design for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

There is something like an security-bot design. In this design a non-service-deamon who not accept any incoming connections and have no db but read/write to/from Microservices using a Regelwerk. Like an arbiter.